# npm - EPERM: operation not permitted on Linux

Tags: node.js, linux, reactjs, npm, npm-install

I'm trying to do the react tutorial on my local machine (centOS)

I ran

```
sudo npm install -g create-react-app
```

After running that command I got the following error

```
npm ERR! Linux 3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "create-react-app"
npm ERR! node v6.10.3
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! path /tmp/npm-1422-84cdbe70/registry.npmjs.org/tar/-/tar-2.2.1.tgz
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -1
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open '/tmp/npm-   1422-84cdbe70/registry.npmjs.org/tar/-/tar-2.2.1.tgz' while getting shasum for /tmp/npm-1422-84cdbe70/registry.npmjs.org/tar/-/tar-2.2.1.tgz
npm ERR! From:     https://registry.npmjs.org/tar/-/tar-2.2.1.tgz
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open '/tmp/npm-1422-84cdbe70/registry.npmjs.org/tar/-/tar-2.2.1.tgz' while getting shasum for /tmp/npm-1422-84cdbe70/registry.npmjs.org/tar/-/tar-2.2.1.tgz
npm ERR! From:     https://registry.npmjs.org/tar/-/tar-2.2.1.tgz
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!   errno: -1,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'open',
npm ERR!   path: '/tmp/npm-1422-84cdbe70/registry.npmjs.org/tar/-/tar-2.2.1.tgz',
npm ERR!   parent: 'tar-pack' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
```

I tried going into the directory and untarring the .tgz file and changing around some of the permissions and nothing worked. I followed some solutions online with similar problems but still no luck.

I also ran

```
npm cache clear
```

Can anyone explain why this is happening? Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried any of this? 
https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions

Comment: @TimeDead Yes, but that deals with EACCES errors wile this is a EPERM error.

Comment: Hmm, have you tried to `chmod` or check the permissions on your `/tmp` folder?

Comment: Yes, I have. Using `ls -l` returns `drwxrwxrwt.  24 root root 4096 Jun  6 07:42 tmp`

Answer (score 0):

Running `npm cache clear` or even `npm cache clear -f`does not always clean all the cache.

Sometimes **you should remove the cache files manually**.
To do so go to the default NPM cache folder and remove its content:

**Default**: `~/.npm` on linux, or `%AppData%/npm-cache` on Windows.

Then you can attempt to install your desired package with `npm install -g`.

Please, **avoid using** `sudo npm install -g` because you can mess up the npm permissions. Instead change the permission to npm's default directory, or change npm's default directory to another directory. Further details here:
https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions

**WARNING:** If npm's default path is just `/usr`, changing the directory permissions will be harmful.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use $: sudo npm install

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).